# Unable to understand grep command : grep -n -o -a --text \"audio uri=\\".*\\""

Tags: python, shell, grep

This command is being used in a Tool written in Python to grep the following string 'audio uri="a852' from the line `<audio uri="a852"/>` in a text file.

But I am unable to understand how `\\` are being used here.

This command normally works in Linux if we remove "\" before "audio uri. 
My understanding to this "\" is it is for using it in the tool i am using written in Python.

Comment: Line is this :  '<audio uri="a852"/>' in a text file.

Comment: possibly should be `grep -n -o -a --text \“audio uri=\\”.*\\“\”` - is the command itself inside double quotes?

Comment: Are you using python to make the system call? Could you put the line of code where it's being called. But the double \\ will result in a single \ to your shell. then the string \" will be interpreted as a qoute mark and not as a string delimiter. So grep will match the string uri=".*"    -- uri= followed directly by anythin between qoutes

Comment: @TimothyMurphy I think you are right. After the Python tool executes this command in my system,  actual command executed is this :  grep -n -o -a --text “audio uri=\”.*\“”   these "\" are for special characters. Thanks!

Comment: "\\" are clear now those were confusing. But i don't understand why we are executing this command with an additional \ before "audio uri. It wouldn't work if we directly execute this command in shell , but works only without \ before audio uri. I think this is to do with Python execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\` is used to cancel the signification of `"`. Here, you have to recognize your `"` to text instead of Bash, to matches `url=".*"`.

For example, you can use `\` like this:

```
mista ~> myname='Mistalis'

mista ~> echo $myname
Mistalis

mista ~> echo \$myname
$myname
```

I think you get a double `\\` because your Python code also needs to cancel the `"`caracter, with a `\`.

If you want to run it on your console, try:
`grep -n -o -a --text “audio uri=\”.*\“”`.
Here I just removed one of the double `\\`.

Comment: Thanks @Mistalis. It was quite usefull.

Comment: Glad I helped. If it resolve your problem, can you accept my answer as the correct answer? :)

Comment: you cleared 30% of the confusion i don't understand why we are executing this command with an additional \ before "audio uri. It wouldn't work if we directly execute this command in shell , but works only without \ before audio uri. I think this is to do with Python execution.